# memory efficient way to make large zeros matrix python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, memory, scipy

I am currently trying to make a really large matrix, i am unsure how to do so in a memory efficient way.

I was trying to use numpy, which worked fine for my smaller case (2750086X300)
However, i got a larger one, 2750086X1000, which is just too big for me to run.

I though about making it out of ints, but I will add float values to it, so unsure how that cld affect it.

I tried find something about making a sparse zero filled array, but cldnt find any great topics/questions/suggestions here or elsewhere.

Anyone got any good advice? I am currently using python so I am kind of looking for a pythonic solution, but i am willing to try other languages.

Thx

---

edit:

thx for advices, i ve tried scipy.sparse.csr_matrix which managed to create a matrix but deeply increased the time to go through it.

heres kind of what i am doing:

```
matrix = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((df.shape[0], 300))
## matrix = np.zeros((df.shape[0], 

for i, q in enumerate(df['column'].values):    

    matrix[i, :] = function(q)
```

where function is pretty much a vector operation function on that row.

Now, if i do the loop on the np.zeros, it does so quite easily, about 10 minuts.

Now, if i try to do the same with the scipy sparse matrix, it takes about 50 hours. which is not that reasonable.

Any advices?

---

Edit 2:

scipy.sparse.lil_matrix did the trick

takes about 20 minut for the loop and uses way less memory than np.zeros

Thx.

---

Edit 3:

still memory expensive. decided to not store data on matrix. process 1 row at a time. get relevant value/metric out of it, store value at original df, run again.

Comment: `np.zeros((2750086, 1000))` could well be too big for your memory, whether filled with zeros or real numbers.  A sparse matrix that has, say only 0.1% non-zeros might fit.  But what are you doing with this array?  Filling it element by element will take for ever. And any math with an array that nearly fills memory will just produce a memory error some where down the line as it creates temporary buffers.

Comment: Think about it, using a 32 bit numbers requires at least `2750086*1000*1e-9*4 =11.000344 gigabytes`. Not totally crazy, but quite big. You can get more RAM or try to work with a sparse representation.

Comment: Search on `[scipy] sparse` to find questions regarding the sparse matrix package in `[scipy]`.  `lil`, `coo`, and `csr` will also work as unique strings.  And if you are doing learning or test processing packages like `scikit-learn` might be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [scipy.sparse.csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html):

```
from scipy.sparse import *
from scipy import *
a=csr_matrix( (2750086,1000), dtype=int8 )
```

Then `a` is

```
<2750086x1000 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int8'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

For example, if you do:

```
from scipy.sparse import *
from scipy import *
a=csr_matrix( (5,4), dtype=int8 ).todense()
print(a)
```

You get:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]]
```

Another options is to use [scipy.sparse.lil_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html)

```
a = scipy.sparse.lil_matrix((2750086,1000), dtype=int8 )
```

This seems to be more efficient for setting elements (like `a[1,1]=2`).